# Facebook fails to redirect to application URL after login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect

I am creating facebook application. If user is not logged on facebook I redirect them to FaceBook login that redirects to my application URL after they logged to facebook. Problem is that user is redirected to facebook.com insted of facebook application URL

Here is code that I am using to check if user logged to FaceBook

```
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      FillInfo();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    window.top.location("https://apps.facebook.com/memorygameonfb/?fb_source=bookmark&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=3_0")
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
window.top.location = "https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=id&skip_api_login=1&display=page&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/memorygameonfb/?fb_source=bookmark&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=3_0";    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason they are being redircted to facebook.com is becasue that is where you are sending them

You need to create `$params` so when your user logs in you can redirect them to your app.

You can find the dox on this [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl)

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page' //This redirects to ur APP!
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

I personally am not great with `JS` I use php for `facebook api` I think it is easier to manage then the `JS API`

If you would like to download a basic app allowing you to login with `php`

[Click Here](https://github.com/wuno/Facebook-Login-Example) 

and follow the `readme file` for instructions.